# I'm getting a java.lang.StackOverflowError in my quicksort

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, quicksort

This is basicly a simple quicksort whiche uses arraylists but I can't find the reason why I get stuck in an endless recursion. In the end the only reslut I get is a stack overflow error.

```
 List<Integer> quicksort(List<Integer> toSort){

        if(toSort.size() > 1){
            List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0;i<toSort.size();i++){
                if(toSort.get(i) < toSort.get(toSort.size()/2))
                    left.add(toSort.get(i));
                else
                    right.add(toSort.get(i));
            }

            toSort = quicksort(left);
            toSort.addAll(quicksort(right));
            return toSort;

        }else
            return toSort;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you add some print statements in your program so you can see what it's doing - or what it's not doing. You shouldn't need to increase your stack size.

Comment: There might be too much recursion, you may want to increase your stack size or alternatively do this on heap releasing the stacks.

Comment: I already did debug the code at some point I end up at a state, where right list includes 3 itemes and the left one 0. Now the recursion goes over and over with the same items

Comment: I did try and highlight this below, but basically, any time you select a pivot which is the smallest element (this can happen at _any_ iteration) you'll end up infinite-recursing.  I'd start with changing the _LESS THAN_ to a _LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO_ test so there's at least _some_ splitting happening.  But I don't believe that will resolve the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have 2 elements in your `toSort` `List` (when it's first called), `[2, 1]`.

First, you create two `List`s, `left` and `right`.

You then populate these based on the 'pivot'.  You use `toSort.get(toSort.size() / 2);` as the pivot.  `toSort.size()` = 2, so `toSort.get(1)` = 1 (from the `List` above) in this case.

You then add the elements to different `List`s based on whether they are *LESS THAN* this value.  So that means you end up with (after the `for` loop has completed):

`left = []`, `right = [2, 1]`.

You then call `quickSort` on both of these `List`s again.  Second time round, when calling `toSort.addAll(quicksort(right));` you're back in the *exact* state as your first call, and so the above just happens again.  Eventually this results in a stack overflow.

---

Your problem here is that you have mis-implemented the quicksort algorithm.  I'd recommend reviewing the pseudo-code for the quicksort algorithm that you based your implementation from, and working through smaller steps of it at a time (and then asking for help when you identify the smallest step that you're misunderstanding).